# The mentioned syntax error was in this case item using Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am having difficulty to understand what I am doing wrong in the script. The purpose of the script is to grant or revoke access based on the parameters passed to the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVER_IP_FILE=""
DEV_USER_KEY_FILE=""
USER=`whoami`
DEV_USER=""
MODE=""

showHelp() {

    cat << EOF
    ...
    EOF
}

grant_access()
{
    while $line in `cat $SERVER_IP_FILE`
    do
        ssh $USER@$line sudo useradd $DEV_USER -d /home/$DEV_USER -G developer
        ssh $USER@$line sudo mkdir /home/$DEV_USER/.ssh
        ssh $USER@$line sudo touch /home/$DEV_USER/.ssh/authorized_keys
        ssh $USER@$line sudo cat $DEV_USER_KEY_FILE > /home/$DEV_USER/.ssh/authorized_keys
        ssh $USER@$line sudo chown -R $dev_user:$dev_user /home/$DEV_USER/.ssh
    done
}


revoke_access()
{
    while $line in `cat $SERVER_IP_FILE`
    do
        ssh $USER@$line sudo userdel $DEV_USER
        ssh $USER@$line sudo rm -rf /home/$DEV_USER/.ssh
    done
}

while getops "hfkum" opt; do
    case "${opt}" in
        -h|--help)
            showHelp
            # Shows help for running script.
            ;;
        -f|--ip-file)
            SERVER_IP_FILE=$opt
            # File which contains IP addresses of server group.
            ;;
        -k|--key-file)
          DEV_USER_KEY_FILE=$opt
            # Public key file of the user who's access needs to be granted or revoked
            ;;
        -u|--user)
          DEV_USER=$opt
            # Username who needs to be granted access or revoked
            ;;
        -m|--mode)
            MODE=$opt
            # Mode of operation. It must be either grant or revoke
            ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND -1))

if [ $MODE == 'grant' ] ;
then
        grant_access()
elif [ $MODE == 'revoke' ] ;
then
        revoke_access()
else
        echo "Wrong mode. Mode must be either grant or revoke"
fi
```

I am expecting to run script like below.

```
access.sh -m grant -f staging_server_ip.txt -k id_rsa.pub -u test-user
access.sh -m revoke -f staging_server_ip.txt -k id_rsa.pub -u test-user
```

and then it would do the desired operation. When I check script [here](https://www.shellcheck.net/)
it gives me error on line 58, 59 and 62. I don't understand what I am doing wrong with syntax.

Comment: Run your code through https://www.shellcheck.net/ - this tool will highlight many issues automatically.

Comment: That's where I checked and came to know about the errors. I am not able to understand the syntax error.

Comment: `showHelp()` should be `showHelp` and each case should end in `;;`.

Comment: It helps to show the errors you're receiving in the post too.

Comment: I updated the bash code but still have errors.

Comment: You have a number of issues here.  Start with removing the parens from grant_access and remove_access in the if/elif statement (lines 81 and 84) and you'll see the issues better.

Comment: `getops` should be `getopts`. Also, `getopts` only understands single-letter options, and the dash is removed, so the case statements only should compare against `h` or `k`, not `-h|--help` or `-k|--key-file`.

Comment: *＋1* for asking a Bash question that has to do with programming and development, and includes program control flow (and not just how to run a command).

Answer (score 1):

Use "bash -n myscript.sh" to test the syntax of your script.

In lines 81 and 84 you called functions with "()" which cause a syntax error.

Remove the "()" from lines 81 and 84 to fix your script's syntax:

```
if [ $MODE == 'grant' ] ;
then
        grant_access
elif [ $MODE == 'revoke' ] ;
then
        revoke_access
else
        echo "Wrong mode. Mode must be either grant or revoke"
fi
```